# questions with dropped/500 compared with cloud run (cloud native)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-run

I have a quick question. I've been running my APIs on a virtual machine (VM). However, when the traffic becomes too high, the VM seems to drop packets and I receive 500 internal errors. On the other hand, when I run the APIs on Cloud Run, which is routed through the GCP load balancer, even though Cloud Run doesn't have containers up initially, this setup seems to hold the connection longer and eventually responds, although the response time increases slightly. Since this application is an automation workflow that runs in the background, reliability is more important than response time.

Here are my questions:

1. Is the ability to hold the connection related to the GCP load balancer or the Knative Cloud Run setup? If it's the latter, will Kubernetes hold the connection instead of dropping it?
2. Is the VM dropping the connection due to the Nginx load balancer or is it just a VM issue?
3. Do you have any other recommendations for a similar setup to the GCP load balancer and Cloud Run?

I'm asking these questions because running on Cloud Run is nice since it auto-scales and I have load tested it, and it scales well without dropping connections. However, it's not ideal for me because I prefer using AWS for other services like Lambda functions, networking, S3 buckets, and Step Functions for my application.

Of course, I can test the various scenarios but wanted to see if anybody had any technical insight on this.  Thanks :)

Comment: In Google Cloud, the network is virtualized. I doubt that packets are being dropped. Typically, an HTTP Status 500 means there was an issue with the application. However, your question lacks details to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Cloud Run (Managed) is based on gVisor, Borg and the GFE. Knative and Kubernetes are not part of Cloud Run (Managed). Cloud Run will queue requests. For Compute Engine, your instance size must be large enough to handle the request rate and the clients calling your API should be implementing [Exponential Backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) and retrying requests. Your service should be reporting the correct HTTP Status Code (429/503) when the service is reaching capacity limits.

Comment: hi john, thanks a bunch.  sorry if i wasn't clear.  i didn't mean google cloud was dropping packets.  in fact, it maintains and the api is almost always serviced.  if i use a vm, then the packets are dropped and it returns a 500.  so google is nice since i don't need to size the application since it autoscales.  i just prefer aws.  i'll read up on exponential backoff.  thanks!

Comment: in hindsight, it may also have something to do with my nginx load balancer in the vm in comparison the google load balancer and how it responds.  i'll investigate more.